# Why does the reduction of "sloshing" in tankers also reduce brake distance?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, mass, friction

After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56cxOzgl-mc&ab_channel=ScanscotTechnologyAB), I was confused at why reducing the peak slosh force made braking easier, after all it's the same mass inside the truck, plus, shouldn't the overall force over the whole braking distance (area under curve) be the same, only the peak force being decreased?

Does this have to do with the rear tyres being unloaded and thus having less brake force? or is it something else?